# candlestick ... using mpl_finance

Tags: matplotlib, plot

ok i have my dataframe as below
datanew['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close']

i am using subplots... and i cant seem to figure how the syntax ...

kept getting a error .. using mpl_finance

```
   f,ax = plt.subplots(
    nrows=4, ncols=1, sharex=True, sharey=False, 
    gridspec_kw={'height_ratios':[3,8,4,3]}
    )
    f.set_figheight(18)
   f.set_figwidth(18)


  #visualize data n strategy 
  bbox_props = dict(boxstyle='round',fc='w', ec='k',lw=1)

  #Price
  #ax[1].plot(datanew['Price'],label = stock,alpha=0.5,linewidth=2)
  ax[1].plot.candlestick(datanew['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close'] , width=0.6, colorup='green', 
 colordown='red', alpha=0.8)

  ax[1].plot(datanew['Short8EMA'],label='8 EMA',alpha=0.75,linewidth=2)
  ax[1].plot(datanew['Long21EMA'],label='21 EMA',alpha=0.75,linewidth=2)
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Please post the full stack trace.

Comment: thnks for responding 
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-041a9713f8d0> in <module>()
    258   #ax[1].plot(datanew['Price'],label = stock,alpha=0.5,linewidth=2)
    259 
--> 260   ax[1].plot.candlestick(datanew['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close'] , width=0.6, colorup='green', colordown='red', alpha=0.8)
    261   #ax[1].plot(datanew['SMA30'],label='SMA30',alpha=0.75,linewidth=2)
    262   #ax[1].plot(datanew['SMA100'],label='SMA100',alpha=0.75,linewidth=2)

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'candlestick'

Comment: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

 #   Column               Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------               --------------  -----  
 0   Date                 150 non-null    object 
 1   Price                150 non-null    float64
 2   Open                 150 non-null    float64
 3   Close                150 non-null    float64
 4   High                 150 non-null    float64
 5   Low                  150 non-null    float64
 6   Volume               150 non-null    float64

Comment: i am guessing its my data frame as my date col is a index

Comment: or another issue if the date format use by MPL ... not very sure ..

Comment: i found the error is due to my data frame ..
when i list it out 
datanew['Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close']

it shows the error

       KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
       /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in 
       get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
       2645             try:
       -> 2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
       2647             except KeyError:

Answer (score -1):

ok i resolved this issue...

it was my dataframe apparently i had to reformat the date column as it was my index for other parts of the plot using matplotlib just for using mpl_finance candlestick .. it works fine now [image: code fixed]